# Reinitialize/Refresh Flexslider within Colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox, flexslider

I have a Flexslider within Jquery Colorbox, but the Flexslider is not given a height, and needs to be re-initialized upon the colorbox loading. I have the following code, the colorbox is loading, however the flexslider doesn't seem to be re-loading. Can anyone pinpoint the problem?

```
     $(".group1").colorbox({      
             href: function(){ return $(this).attr('href') + " #lightbox1"; },
            width: 750,
            height: 550,
            opacity: .7, 
            oncomplete: function() { $('.flexslider').flexslider();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My On complete was incorrect it needed to be:

```
   $(".group1").colorbox({      
             href: function(){ return $(this).attr('href') + " #lightbox1"; },
            width: 750,
            height: 550,
            opacity: .7, 
               'onComplete' : function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider();
 }            
   });
```